# Не запускается тест

Tags: java, maven, юнит-тесты, тестирование

Не могу запустить тест.
Описание проблемы: мне скинули гит хаб https://github.com/AntonBalakirev/selenium_script  с которого я скачал маленький проект с одним лишь тестом и попытался запустить его у себя, не получилось. Вообще нету зелёной кнопочки сбоку как отмечено на скринах ниже красным кружочком. Ок, я создал элементарный тест в идее в новом проекте, что бы увидеть эту кнопочку и туда копернуть этот файл, но увы и там этой кнопочки я не нашёл. Буду благодарен за любые мысли по этому поводу

Это pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">


<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>Test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Это код класса

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class oooTest {

@Test
public void getAllUsers() {
    //создаем тестовые данные
    System.out.println("123");
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все работает. Откройте панель maven справа и обновите зависимости. Хотя я бы подумал перед тем как запускать exe файл, скачанный непонятно откуда.

Comment: @AlekseiGaile
Так зависимости и так подтянуты, если бы мавен не подтянул junit, то анотация (Собака)Test вообще бы красным подчеркивалась, но я всё равно сделал Reimport и не помогло.

Comment: а какая стоит IDEA, Ultimate или Community?